# How can numpy be used to split up matrices, avoiding nested for-loops?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop, matrix

My code could run faster if I convert the following function by avoiding the nested for loops and instead using numpy-functions.
The input is a numpy-matrix, shaped (8, 96, 3), according two (rows, cols, RGB-color). The output needs to 3 arrays, each representing an LED-matrix. The LED-matrices are organized in a serpentine way (found on [Github](https://github.com/jwalanta/whiterabbit#neomatrix-layout)) :

```
  x - x - x - x - x - x - x --- to raspberry pi
  |
  |
  x - x - x - x - x - x - x 
                          |
                          |
  x - x - x - x - x - x - x 
  |
  |
  x - x - x - x - x - x - x 
                          |
                          |
  x - x - x - x - x - x - x
```

The code for splitting up the matrix into these 3 arrays looks like this:

```
    def matrix_to_array(self, matrix):
    arr1 = []
    arr2 = []
    arr3 = []
    rows = len(matrix)
    cols = len(matrix[0])
    for r in range(rows):
        for c in range(cols):
            c = 95 - c          
            if c <= 31:
                if r % 2 == 1:
                    arr1.append(matrix[7-r][31-c])
                else:
                    arr1.append(matrix[7-r][c])
            elif c <= 63:
                if r % 2 == 1:
                    arr2.append(matrix[7-r][31-c+64])
                else:
                    arr2.append(matrix[7-r][c])                 
            else:
                if r % 2 == 1:
                    arr3.append(matrix[7-r][63-c])
                else:
                    arr3.append(matrix[7-r][c])
    return arr3+arr2+arr1
```

Now, how can this be optimized using numpy, but still keeping the transformations as required for the LED-matrix setup?
Thank you so much for helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This piece of code gives exactly the same result as your code...
But without the column loop.

```py
def matrix_to_array(self, matrix):
    arr1 = []
    arr2 = []
    arr3 = []
    for r in range(0, len(matrix), 2):
        arr1 += list(np.concatenate((matrix[-r - 1, :32][::-1], matrix[-r - 2, :32])))
        arr2 += list(np.concatenate((matrix[-r - 1, 32:64][::-1], matrix[-r - 2, 32:64])))
        arr3 += list(np.concatenate((matrix[-r - 1, 64:][::-1], matrix[-r - 2, 64:])))

    return arr3 + arr2 + arr1
```

Honestly, was it a programming school exercise ? It felt like it...

Fun to solve :)

Edit :
And here is the hardcore version :D

No more loop, just optimized numpy, you should actually get rid of the final list conversion... it's certainly useless for what you want to do with it...

```py
def matrix_to_array(self, matrix):

    mask = np.array([
        i if i//32 % 2 == 0 else (i//32 + 1)*32 - i % 32 - 1 
        for i in range(32*len(matrix))
    ])

    return list(np.concatenate((
        matrix[:, 64:].reshape((-1, ))[::-1][mask],
        matrix[:, 32:64].reshape((-1, ))[::-1][mask], 
        matrix[:, :32].reshape((-1, ))[::-1][mask]
    )))
```

Comment: Wow this is really great!! Super helpful - thank you so much!

Comment: Was fun to do... Then don't hesitate to "Accept" the answer and click on "the answer is useful" ;)